# Run Android Studio installDebug stay in crashlyticsUploadDeobsDebug for a long time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, crashlytics

I'm open the proguard,project compile is stayed in crashlyticsUploadDeobsDebug,and I also need the source code mapping for proguard

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: Make crashlyticsUploadDeobsDebug finish faster